# How to get the environment from Odoo with the addons write myself?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I try to get the environment of Odoo in shell with :

```
from openerp.modules.registry import RegistryManager
from openerp.api import Environment

r = RegistryManager.get('ethicall')
cr = r.cursor()
Environment.reset()
env = Environment(cr, uid, context={})
```

And when I try to get the models from `env.registry.models`. I only get the models of Odoo.

```
>>> env.registry.models
>>> {'_unknown': _unknown,
'account.account': account.account,
'account.account.template': account.account.template,
'account.account.type': account.account.type,
.....
```

but I search the ir_model table of database "ethicall", it contains more like :

```
 137 | er.base.account.journal                              | 帐户流水                                                                    | base  |      |            |             |           |
 138 | er.base.account                                      | 基础帐户                                                                    | base  |      |            |             |           |
 139 | er.base.budget                                       | 预算计划                                                                    | base  |      |            |             |           |
 140 | er.base.expense                                      | 医时费用计划                                                                | base  |      |            |             |           |          |             |           |
 .....
```

But they do not in `env.registry.models`

if there have some way need to load the addons before I call `env.registry.models` method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot!
I try to read the code of openerp.service.server and find out a way which can get the environment of odoo orm:

```
import openerp 
args = ['-c','openerp-server.conf','-d','testbase']
openerp.tools.config.parse_config(args)

from openerp.modules.registry import RegistryManager
from openerp.api import Environment

r = RegistryManager.get('testbase')
cr = r.cursor()
Environment.reset()
env = Environment(cr, uid, context={})
```

And finally I can use `env['module_name'].search()` method!

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to access environment of odoo from shell you can use **xmlrpc**. with the help of xmlrpc you can call almost every method of the model just modify the execute_kw according to your method.

Here is a demo script which will help you.

```
import xmlrpclib
print "executing..."


url = 'http://192.168.12.130:8069'
db = 'odoo_addons_9c'
username = 'admin'
password = 'a'

common = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/common'.format(url))
models = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/object'.format(url))
uid = common.authenticate(db, username, password, {})

model_ids = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'ir.model', 'search', [[]])
model_datas = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'ir.model', 'read', [model_ids], {'fields': ['name']})

for data in model_datas:
    print data
```

See this [link](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/api_integration.html) for more information.

Hope this helps!